# changing gnuplot graph window name

Tags: gnuplot

I am writing a program that runs on windows that uses Gnuplot to generate dynamic graphs. I need to have multiple graphs running at the same time, so I have multiple threads running different instances of Gnuplot. My problem is that they all have the same title for their graph windows, specifically they all say *Gnuplot (window id:0)*. Is there a way to change this value in Gnuplot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is awkward, but I just found the solution 5 minutes after posting this. I might as well put up my solution in case it helps anybody else.

I just had to use the command:

```
set term wxt title 'my title'
```

where my title is whatever title you want to use.

Comment: ...which applies to the [Wtx terminal driver](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf#section*.486)